# PostgreSQL how to union same table count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

First, my English is not good. I'm sorry.
Therefore I will simply ask questions.

I want to do like this in PostgreSQL

```
kkutu_ko (table)
+----------+------+
|   _id    | type |
+----------+------+
| aexample |    1 |
| bexamplb |    2 |
| cexample |    3 |
| dexa     |    2 |
| easvav   |    3 |
+----------+------+
```

execute sql, I want result like this

```
+----------+------+-------+
|   _id    | type | count |
+----------+------+-------+
| aexample |    1 |     0 |
| bexampld |    2 |     2 |
| cexample |    3 |     0 |
| dexa     |    2 |     1 |
| dasvav   |    3 |     0 |
+----------+------+-------+
```

count "_id" that start with last letter of _id's

example,
(bexampl**d** : dexa, dasvav - count 2)

(dex**a** : aexample - count 1)

I need to use two table..? I want to do this work with one table

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this using a correlated subquery (or lateral join or just a left join):

```
select k.*,
       (select count(*) from kkutu_ko k2 where left(k2._id, 1) = right(k._id, 1)
       ) as cnt
from kkutu_ko k;
```